# Find modified CSS/JS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

So, i'm doing my [website](http://www.dtorres.me), and in the Portafolio section i've implemented the [Overscroll](https://github.com/azoff/Overscroll) plugin to provide the iphone-like scroll but I want it to behave like iOS apps pages when you swipe, then it completes the movement to the "nearest" page. What happens now its that it acts like Google Maps app.

So, the concrete issue is that I haven't been able to find the modified property by the plugin so I can complete the movement (I already have the method to calculate which page or position to give).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(".portfolio .portfolio .showcase").animate({ 'margin-left' : pos });
```

to

```
$("#content .portfolio").animate({ 'scrollLeft' : pos });
```